# How does SAS distinguish missing from non-missing values?

Tags: sas, storage, missing-data

It's commonly said that "SAS missing values equal minus infinity". But There is a problem with that statement, since there can be 27 or 28 "flavors" of missing values (the default `.` and `.a` to `.z` and `._`), each having a predefined sort order.

Since it can't be that some infinities are larger than others, I came to understand that:

1. Missing values are *treated like* minus infinity when compared to valid numerical data, and that
2. When compared to other missing values, they are ranked with another set of predefined rules.

So my question is: at the lowest level, how does SAS store numerical data in a way that it can distinguish the missing from the non-missing numerical values? Is there a "missingness bit" like there is a "sign bit"?

Comment: It isn't actually storing negative infinity explicitly in memory. It's just treated as negative infinity in operations. With multiple missing values it essentially breaks the tie based on the type of missing value.

Comment: And some infinities are larger than others. Try counting every natural number vs counting every real number in [0,1]

Comment: Not at a computer to test, but I believe all numbers are doubles, even missing values.  I think they represent the last 27 (or 28) whole numbers in IEEE double precision floating point representation.  Is `.` > or < `._`?

Comment: Also, SAS is written in C, so you could have a struct behind the scenes managing the "missing-ness" of the value.  Pure speculation on my part.

Comment: @DomPazz It would make sense... For the sort order, it goes that way: `._ < . < .A < ...< .Z < [negative numbers] < 0 < [positive numbers]` -- [source here](http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug01/ps/ps8009.pdf)

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would anyone want to use anything to represent missing other than `.`?  It seems like `.` is pretty much the standard (at least as far as all the code I've ever seen).

Comment: @RobertPenridge It's a practical way to differentiate types of non-responses for survey data, among other possible uses. For instance, "Not Applicable" vs "Refused to answer". But who needs 27 of them, I wonder!

Comment: @Carl About your 1st comment: you're merely rephrasing my question. 2nd comment: you're referring to cardinality of infinitely large sets, not "infinity" per se. See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182171/are-all-infinities-equal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS stores numbers as floating point values using 64bit IEEE format. They picked 28 specific bit combinations and use them to represent ., ._, and .a to .z.  By convention they are ordered ._ to . to .a to .z. I am not sure if the values were picked to make it easier to test that ordering, or if the ordering was an accident of the particular bit patterns they used.

You can look at the bit patterns used by peeking into the values that are stored.

```
data _null_;
  length i 8 str $8 ;
  do i=._,.,.a,.z,constant('small'),0,1,constant('big');
    str=peekclong(addrlong(i));
    str=reverse(str);
    put i best12. @15 i hex16. @35 str $hex16. ;
  end;
run;
```

result

```
           _                 _    FFFFFF0000000000
           .                 .    FFFFFE0000000000
           A                 A    FFFFFD0000000000
           Z                 Z    FFFFE40000000000
2.22507E-308  0010000000000000    0010000000000000
           0  0000000000000000    0000000000000000
           1  3FF0000000000000    3FF0000000000000
1.797693E308  7FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF    7FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: Well, if you remove your two first sentences (I'm sure you can figure out why I say this), I might accept this as an answer.

Comment: The first sentence is in response to the first paragraph of the question.

Comment: I re worded the answer.

Comment: Interesting... so missing doesn't always equal missing: `data _null_; if ._ eq . then do; put 'matches'; end; run;`  Although the `missing()` function can be used to get around this.

Comment: Yes. One of the nice features of SAS that comes in handy when needing to code multiple reasons for missing data.